# How to clear the woocommerce cart when visiting the particular page (outside of wordpress) custom php page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am having the woocommerce store like : example.com/store/

And I am creating the some product sales page in outside of wordpress : example.com/upsell.php

Now I want to clear the cart once you visit the example.com/upsell.php, because we are having multiple step in the upsell and finally we are send a url request to add the products in the cart (example.com/store/cart/?add-to-cart=1,5,8).

Whenever you visit the upsell page we need to clear the cart session.

How can clear the cart session from the upsell page?

Comment: I'm curious as to why would you clear the cart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an action that will clear cart items in template redirect hook.

In the custom function, check the current page slug & then clear the cart as per our condition.

Use the below code snippet in your theme's `functions.php` or custom plugin file.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    global $post;
    $slug = $post->post_name;
    if($slug == 'sample-page') {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you don't like hard coding the page slug, there is also a better method.

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['clear-cart'] ) ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

Add the above code in your theme's `functions.php` file.

Then redirect to a page by adding `clear-cart` query string in your URL & that will clear all cart items.

We can use this function in any URL.

http://example.com?clear-cart

or

http://example.com/sample-page/?clear-cart

Comment: Thanks for your answer, As per your code we will use only wordpress page, How can we use particular page example.com/upsell.php ?

Comment: I tried that,but the cart is still showing the old products.

Comment: @SuriyaKarthikeyan , Why you are using an external page to display upsell product? How you display the product list in that page?

Comment: We didn't call that product details, We have added the product content manually and linked to wordpress by sending the add to cart id like (example.com/shop/cart/?add-to-cart=5,12,15)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have changed all my custom page to wordpress pages. Now I am able to clear the old cart items by using your first update..:)

Comment: @SuriyaKarthikeyan , :-) Can you please update your question title because that never work without API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get the current URL of the page so you can test whether you're on the upsell page.

You'll need to use the following function to clear the cart

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
```

Comment: I have added the following function in the functions.php file, but it getting  error(fatal error)      if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']="http://example.com/upsell.php" ){
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

}

Answer (score 0):

you need to create web api in wp instance which clears cart using this code

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
```

and call that api on upsell.php file. You can even use HTTP_REFERER to check whether user directly hit the upsell.php url or not.